# How to whiten a white shirt with black designs that has turned a discolored white/yellow(ish)

Tags: cleaning, laundry

I have a printed (black) graphic T Shirt (white) where the design has held up very well over the years. When I moved all my clothing to my new place, I noticed that many of my shirts (button up blends, cotton white t shirts, etc) started turning yellow in my new location. And when I say discolored/yellow, I mean the entire shirt(s).

[image: https://i.imgur.com/YeAnem7.jpg]
(I added some white pants, an envelope, and a black/white striped scarf, for comparison.)

Maybe it was the different minerals in the tap water or that I left my closet light on all the time or something else... I have no idea.

**How can I get this shirt to be whiter without screwing up the design?**

Comment: It seems that your t-shirt has reached the stage of "nothing is eternal". I am not claiming that there are no solutions (maybe there are), but you might want  taking into consideration looking for a nice frame for it - especially if it has sentimental value.

Answer (score 1):

1. Test to see if the issue *is* caused by iron or manganese by using a *reducing agent*, e.g. the sodium hydrosulfite and sodium bisulfite in a product such as [Red-B-Gone](https://red-b-gone.com/) or [Iron Out](https://summitbrands.com/product-category/iron-out/).

   - Test an inconspicuous yellowed spot to see if it is lightened.
   - Test an inconspicuous black spot to see if it is damaged.
2. Check if the yellowing is a stain that can be removed with dilute chlorine bleach, **testing inconspicuous areas** as above.

Since we don't know the materials used for the fabrics, or for the inks, the responsibility to test is yours.

Comment: Its 100% cotton. The ink.. no clue.
Thank you for your advice